# How can I get only the dates that are less than two years old?

Tags: python, numpy

```py
np_arr = np.array([
      [2818, 'Daniel', 'within an hour', '2008-09-24', 4.89, 2.86, 't', 't'],
      [5820, 'Sam', 'within an week', '2020-10-24', 4.89, 2.86, 't', 't'],
      [5420, 'Franc', 'within an second', '2019-11-24', 4.89, 2.86, 't', 't'],
      [5520, 'Sandra', 'within an second', '2019-01-24', 4.89, 2.86, 't', 't']
              ])
host_since = np_arr[:,3].astype(np.datetime64) 
filter = (datetime.now() - host_since.astype('datetime64[M]')).years < 2
filter
```

How can I get only the dates that are less than two years old?
The True/False array should look like this:

```py
array([[False, True, True, False])
```

Comment: @QuangHoang @ Dani Mesejo thank you. Copy & Paste mistake :/. It should now work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current time, and duration should also be in `np.datetime64` format

- `np.datetime64(datetime.now())`
- `np.timedelta64(2 * 365, 'D')`

```
np_arr = np.array([
    [2818, 'Daniel', 'within an hour', '2008-09-24', 4.89, 2.86, 't', 't'],
    [5820, 'Sam', 'within an week', '2020-10-24', 4.89, 2.86, 't', 't'],
    [5420, 'Franc', 'within an second', '2019-11-24', 4.89, 2.86, 't', 't'],
    [5520, 'Sandra', 'within an second', '2019-01-24', 4.89, 2.86, 't', 't']
])
host_since = np_arr[:, 3].astype(np.datetime64)
result = (np.datetime64(datetime.now()) - host_since) < np.timedelta64(2 * 365, 'D')
print(result)  # [False  True  True False]
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're defining year as 12 months. Then try:

```
month_diff = np.array(datetime.now(), 'datetime64[M]') - host_since.astype('datetime64[M]')

mask = month_diff < np.array(24, 'timedelta64[M]')
```

Output:

```
array([False,  True,  True, False])
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to compute the difference in days and find the values that are less than `2 * 365` days:

```
host_since = np_arr[:, 3].astype(str).astype(np.datetime64)
delta =  np.datetime64('today') - host_since
print(delta < np.timedelta64(2 * 365, 'D'))
```

**Output**

```
[False  True  True False]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's datetime module:

```py
# Timedelta function demonstration 
  
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
  
  
# Using current time
now = datetime.now()

# 730 is two years
twoYearsAgo = now - timedelta(days = 730)
  
print('2 years ago:', str(twoYearsAgo))
```

Note: This doesn't account for leap years